# Norm is weakly lower semicontinuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is it the case that for every normed space, the norm is always weakly lower semicontinuous? Does it also hold for topologies other than the weak one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One can show that for a given real-valued function $f$ the equivalence $$f \, \text{convex, lower semicontinuous} \, \Leftrightarrow \, f \, \text{convex, weakly lower semicontinuous}$$

holds. Since the norm $f(x) := \|x\|$ is convex and continuous (by the triangle inequality), the claim follows.

Moreover, for any topology $\mathcal{S}$ finer as the weak topology $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}$-lower semicontinuity implies $\mathcal{S}$-lower semicontinuity right from the definition: Let $(x_n)_n$ a sequence such that $x_n \to x$ in $(X,\mathcal{S})$, then $x_n \to x$ in $(X,\mathcal{T})$ since $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$. Consequently, by the $\mathcal{T}$-lower semicontinuity $$f(x) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} f(x_n).$$

Comment: shouldn't you have used nets instead of sequence ?

Comment: I know its trivial but can you give me a reference for the 1st equivalence?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a direct argument. Let $X$ be a normed space. We want to show that, for any $\lambda \geq 0$, the set $\{ x \in X : \|x\| \leq \lambda\}$ is weakly closed. Let $x_i$  be a net in this set converging weakly to $x \in X$. By Hahn-Banach, there is a $\varphi \in X^*$ with $\|\varphi\| = 1$ such that $\varphi(x) = \|x\|$. By weak convergence,
$$\|x\| = \varphi(x) =\lim_i \varphi(x_i) = \lim_i |\varphi(x_i)| \leq \sup_i \|x_i\| \leq \lambda$$
so the claim holds.

Comment: The infimum in the inequality $\lim_i |\varphi(x_i)| \leq \inf_i \|x_i\|$ should be replaced by $\liminf_i$ because nothing prevents a few $x_i$ from having small norm. Another direct argument would be to write $\{x \in X : \|x\| \leq \lambda\} = \bigcap_{\|\varphi\| = 1} \varphi^{-1}([-\lambda,\lambda])$ and the right hand side is obviously weakly closed.

Comment: Sure, that's also fine, so +1 :-) As a matter of principle I'd slightly prefer stating it in the form $\| x \| \leq \liminf_{i} \|x_i\|$ for weakly convergent nets $x_i \to x$, because it's sharper at no cost and actually is an equivalent and useful form of stating weak lower semicontinuity.

Comment: Could you explain the application of Hahn Banach here? The set on the left hand side does not seem to necessarily be linear, and hence I don't see how Hahn Banach can be invoked. Thanks!!!

Mark

Comment: @Mark: I guess technically what I'm using is a standard corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem. See the 3rd bullet point in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Important_consequences

Comment: Please, where is $\|\varphi\| = 1$ used?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: It's used to get $\lim |\varphi(x_i)| \leq \sup \|x_i\|$. The assumption on $\varphi$ gives $|\varphi(x_i)| \leq \|x_i\|$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be a normed space. We want to show that, for any $\lambda \ge 0$, the set $\{ x \in X: \| x \| \le \lambda \}$ is weakly closed.

Firstly, the set $\{x \in X: \| x \| \le \lambda \}$ is convex. Secondly, $\{x \in X: \| x \| \le \lambda \}$ is closed in the norm topology.
Hence the result follows from the fact that a convex sets closure is the closure in the weak topology.